# MimeMessage Content Type java

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, mime-types

```
StringBuffer messageText = new StringBuffer();
messageText.append("<style type=\"text/css\">" +
                    "#message p {some style }" +
                    "</style>");
messageText.append("<p>");
(L1)messageText.append("abc’s email level…def");            
messageText.append("</p>");
message.setContent(messageText.toString(), "text/html;");
Transport.send(message);
```

When i ran the code found two different variations of the output.

I first typed this message `abc’s email level…def` in the microsoft word, then copied this to the eclipse editor. when i run the program message that was in email is something different like this `abc?s email level?def`

But when i type this message `abc’s email level…def` in the eclipse editor then I am seeing the same message in email.

What should I change in the code to receive the same message in the email even if i copy something from microsoft word...

Comment: This is probably related to Word's "smart" quotes - I am not sure there is a lot you can do unless you past via a text editor such a Notepad++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly an encoding problem between your editors (MS-Word and Eclipse, in this case) and your program. You'll want to verify that the content you are copying and pasting from MS-Word to eclipse is UTF-8 on both sides, I suspect that it is not.

The commenter is right that this problem is problem microsoft's smart quotes, which don't generally paste correctly, you can write a [regular expression to replace them](http://axonflux.com/handy-regexes-for-smart-quotes); but this is a specific work around for those particular characters, and will not handle a generic case.

The root cause is almost certainly an encoding mismatch between what you are pasting from MS-Word, and what your java code expects. You can check your eclipse settings to verify you are using UTF-8 as a default, check your word settings to verify the source document is also UTF-8.